# Double integrals, fraction of reflected intensity, Mary L Boas

Tags: calculus

I am currently working through multiple integrals and came across a question that has had me stumped for some time. Essentially, I am asking for a second opinion on this. 
This is the question -

> A partially silvered mirror covers the square area with vertices at $(+/- 1, +/- 1)$. The fraction of incident light which it reflects at $(x,y)$ is $\frac{(x-y)^2}{4}$. Assuming a uniform intensity of incident light, find the fraction reflected.

The book quoted answer is $\frac{1}{6}$. However, I believe the correct answer is $\frac{2}{3}$. The only way I can find to get the book answer is to set up this double integral, 
$\int_0^1dy\int_0^1\frac{(x-y)^2}{4}dx$, and multiply it by 4, which **does** get $\frac{1}{6}$. However I think this makes no sense, because the surface above the four quadrants of the x-y plane, $z = \frac{(x-y)^2}{4}$, is not symmetrical about these four quadrants, so surely you couldn't just multiply that double integral, which correctly gets the reflected intensity above the first quadrant of the x-y plane, by 4. I think the actual solution is to either, set the bottom limits for the double integral above to -1, which gets $\frac{2}{3}$, or to set up two seperate double integrals and work out the reflected intensity in neighbouring (non-diagonal, as they reflect the same?) quadrants, multiply each by 2 and sum them both which, I believe, gets $\frac{2}{3}$.
Am I -

1. Making a stupid mistake somewhere that I cannot see.
2. Correct and Mary L Boas is wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is a question about mathematics rather than physics.

Answer (score 1):

The total amount of incident light is $\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^1 dx\,dy = 4$ and the total reflected light is $\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^1 \tfrac{1}{4}(x - y)^2\, dx\,dy = 2/3$. The fraction reflected is $(2/3)/4 = 1/6$.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your answer of 2/3. As you noted, the $f(x,y) = \frac{(x-y)^2}{4}$ is not symmetric under reflection symmetry about the $x$ or $y$ axes, so it makes no sense to evaluate the integral over one quadrant and multiply it by 4. Instead $f(x,y)$ has this behaviour:
[image]

Clearly the 4 quadrants do not give the same contributions to the integral. The upper-left and lower right quadrants each give 1/24, while the other two quadrants give 7/24, giving a total of 2/3. This is also the answer you obtain by simply integrating the function over the whole range.

So I believe the answer is (2), that there is an error in Boas' book.

Answer (score 0):

Writing $(x-y)^2 = x^2+y^2-2xy$, the squares give 4/3 each, noting the a factor of 2 from the second dimension. The cross term is antisymmetric in x and y, so contributes zero. After dividing by 4 I find 2/3, indeed.